# Page Curl Between Two Activities

Tags: android

Is it possible to perform page curl effect while going from one activity to another as same as iPhone.
After searching on google, every where I found that in android we can perform page curl between two views. 
If this is possible between two activities then HOW ?

Comment: AFAIK, it might be achieved only by customizing the `Android` sources.

Comment: How, can you share any example ?